# how to insert two lists as values to a dictionary to the same key

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose `mydict = {'key1': ['value1', 'value2'],'key2': ['value1', 'value2']}`

Here I want to append or add another list (Say `['NewValue1', 'NewValue2']`) to the Entity with key `"key1"` such that it will become like

```
mydict = {'key1': ['value1', 'value2'],['NewValue1', 'NewValue2'] ,'key2': ['value1', 'value2']}
```

And in future I want to access all the lists under the key `"key1"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the lists in the dictionary to list of lists.

```
>>> mydict = {'key1': [['value1', 'value2']],'key2': [['value1', 'value2']]}
```

Now you can easily append a new list to any of the key and later access individual lists under a key using either a for-loop or indexing.

```
>>> mydict['key1'].append(['NewValue1', 'NewValue2'])
>>> mydict
{'key2': [['value1', 'value2']],
 'key1': [['value1', 'value2'], ['NewValue1', 'NewValue2']]}
```